Authorization process for integrating Slack with Microsoft's Bot Framework
We are utilizing https://slack.botframework.com/Home/auth/v2 as the redirect_url in our Slack OAuth authorization flow. This URL is associated with the Microsoft Bot Framework and is part of the process to authorize and connect bots to Slack workspaces.
Our application is built using the Microsoft Bot Framework, which simplifies the integration of bots with various messaging platforms, including Slack.
Initiating Authorization: When a user initiates the authorization process to add our bot to their Slack workspace, they are directed to Slack's authorization page.
Handling 'Allow' Button: Once the user clicks the 'Allow' button, the authorization flow completes successfully. We have configured a Landing Page URL in Azure to handle this event, redirecting users to a specific page upon successful authorization.
Challenge with 'Cancel' Button:
Lack of Redirection for 'Cancel': Unlike the 'Allow' button, the 'Cancel' button does not have a configurable option for redirection within the Azure Slack integration. This means that when a user clicks 'Cancel', there is no specific URL or page to redirect them to
Or perhaps there's an option to connect the Bot Framework after the slack authorization flow.
Is there a solution for this?
I have tried to connect Bot Framework with custom slack authorization.
